# How to kill Mono program properly

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop

I'm currently working on a cross-platform app written in C#. I have a huge problem with testing and debugging it under Linux/Mono. When my application hangs due to an error, I have to kill the process (either using stop button in MonoDevelop debugger or using kill(all) command). The problem is, that after killing I cannot start the application again. When restarted from console, it waits a second or two and exits, showing nothing as output. When started from MonoDevelop, debugger loads some assemblies and then the process exits with no error. There seems to be no Mono-related service in process table. The only way to start the application again is to log off and log in again.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your C# program using some external service (ie making requests to some database, to some web services, ....)? Is it doing some socket operations? Tell us more about your application... Also, perhaps `strace`-ing your app could help you.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about strace utility. After analysis of output, I found the answer. Our application uses IPC to communicate with other process instances. Under Linux, Mono IPC is creating some temp files in ~/.local/share/AppName. When killed, these files must be removed manually to "invalidate" IPC mutexes.

Comment: @Andrzej, I believe this comment deserves to be posted as an answer and self-accepted by you )